# Total number of cells containing a specific font color

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm Trying to create a program to **total the amount of cells containing green and red font in column A among all the sheets in the workbook.**

In the provided code below the code it counts **ALL** the cells containing green and red font in **column A** of the worksheets.

Please be sure to leave a comment if you can guide me in the right direction!

I also made an example google sheet of what im trying to accomplish: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yLfCxaT-cIl_W77Y67xdg_ZTSQlg9X2a5vxAH4JtDpk/edit?usp=sharing

```
' If it's not going to return something, you can define this as a procedure (sub) and not a function
Sub Test_It()

    Dim mySheet As Worksheet ' Define as worksheet if you're going to loop through sheets and none is a Graph/Chart sheet

    Dim printRow As Integer ' Beware that integer it's limited to 32k rows (if you need more, use Long)
    printRow = 2


    For Each mySheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets ' use the mySheet object previously defined

        Range("N" & printRow).Value = "Sheet Name:"
        Range("O" & printRow).Value = mySheet.Name
        Range("P" & printRow).Value = "Approval:"
        Range("Q" & printRow).Value = SumGreen(mySheet) ' you can pass the sheet as an object
        Range("R" & printRow).Value = "Refused:"
        Range("S" & printRow).Value = SumRed(mySheet)
        printRow = printRow + 1
    Next mySheet

End Sub

-------------------------------------------

Function SumGreen(mySheet As Worksheet) As Long ' define the type the function is going to return

    Dim myCell As Range

    Dim counter As Long

    For Each myCell In mySheet.UsedRange.Columns("A") ' UsedRange is the range that has information

        If myCell.Font.Color = RGB(112, 173, 71) Then ' 255 is red, not green, change to whatever you need

            counter = counter + 1 ' change to counter + mycell.value if you have values and you want to sum them

        End If

    Next myCell

    ' Set the function to return the counter
    SumGreen = counter

End Function

-------------------------------------------


Function SumRed(mySheet As Worksheet) As Long ' define the type the function is going to return

    Dim myCell As Range

    Dim counter As Long

    For Each myCell In mySheet.UsedRange.Columns("A") ' UsedRange is the range that has information

        If myCell.Font.Color = 255 Then ' 255 is red, not green, change to whatever you need

            counter = counter + 1 ' change to counter + mycell.value if you have values and you want to sum them

        End If

    Next myCell

    ' Set the function to return the counter
    SumRed = counter

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the cells, not the range:

```
Function SumGreen(mySheet As Worksheet) As Long

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = mySheet.UsedRange.Columns("A")
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim counter As Long

    For Each cel In rng.Cells 'add .Cells here and it works like a charm
        If myCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then
           counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next myCell

    SumGreen = counter

End Function
```

Comment: Ding Ding Ding!! Thanks so much! I did have to edit a few things in the function, but i got it working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your green color is not RGB(112, 173, 71), try so

```
Sub Test_It()

    Dim mySheet As Worksheet 
    Dim printRow As Integer
    printRow = 2
    For Each mySheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Range("A" & printRow).Value = mySheet.Name
        Range("B" & printRow).Value = SumGreen(mySheet)
        Range("C" & printRow).Value = SumRed(mySheet)
        printRow = printRow + 1
    Next mySheet
End Sub
Function SumGreen(mySheet As Worksheet) As Long 
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim counter As Long
    For Each myCell In mySheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells ' <<<< changed
        If myCell.Font.Color = 65280 Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next myCell
    ' Set the function to return the counter
    SumGreen = counter
End Function

Function SumRed(mySheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim counter As Long
    For Each myCell In mySheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
        If myCell.Font.Color = 255 Then ' 255 is red
            counter = counter + 1 
        End If
    Next myCell
    ' Set the function to return the counter
    SumRed = counter
End Function
```

Comment: This code works, but I found the RGB code from the font color that was used in the sheet. Also, this doesn't read column A, it reads the entire sheet.

Comment: In my code I used the command `mySheet.UsedRange.Columns("A")` but it gives me an error and wont run.

Comment: use UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells, I changed the above code